# Enforce code coverage to be applied only to PR's with 5 or more lines of code related changes

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to only apply code coverage to pull requests that have 5 lines of code related changes? We have some PR's where there will only be one line change, but team hasn't been able to cover that line for different reasons. Therefore, is there a way to enforce code coverage requirements for PRs that have less than 5 line changes?

Comment: You shouldn't have code coverage requirements at all. Code coverage is not an indicator of code quality.

Comment: Right, but it is an enforcement for developers to provide tests and ensure quality.

Comment: That's exactly what code review during a PR is for: to ensure that valid tests are being written that actually improve quality. You can write garbage tests to pump up coverage without ensuring quality to sneak around coverage requirements. Coverage requirements are just an arbitrary additional hoop that people need to jump through.